# Composer PHP: como carregar "repositories" depois de "autoload"

Tags: php, composer, packages, autoload

estou com uma dúvida/problema referente ao composer php.
Vamos lá, meus projetos em PHP agora são em sua maioria utilizando composer, para "modularizar" algumas partes comecei a usar a propriedade **repositories** no composer.json.

Eu estou tentando usar [esse pacote](https://github.com/EvelynGitHub/SimpleCrudPhp) SimpleCrudPhp. Eu clono o repositório em uma pasta chamada **modules** em meu projeto e no `composer.json` coloco:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./modules/SimpleCrudPhp"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src",
        },
        "files": [
            "env.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "simplephp/simple-crud": "dev-master"
    }
```

**O problema** é que o pacote SimpleCrudPhp precisa executar o arquivo *Config.php* que pega as variáveis de ambientes carregadas no autoload no arquivo *env.php*, mas como o SimpleCrudPhp executa primeiro que o *env.php* ele não pega as variáveis de ambiente e acaba não funcionando.

**Obs.:** Quando coloco um `require __DIR__ . "../../../../env.php";` dentro do *Config.php* ele funciona, mas não quero uma solução que tem que ficar modificando algo dentro do pacote.

Eu gostaria de saber se tem como modificar o *composer.json* do projeto principal para que ele carregue esse **repositories** (SimpleCrudPhp) depois do **autoload/autoload-dev**? Ou então alguma abordagem que possa utilizar para fazer o pacote funcionar sem que eu tenha que modificar seu conteúdo toda vez que criar um novo projeto?

Desde já, obrigada.

Comment: Vê se isso dá um ajuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745691/cant-get-composer-path-repository-to-work

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada, mas o dev-master não é o problema, o pacote funciona, mas por carregar depois do env.php, não pega o valor das variáveis para o define()

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que acredito, o Composer sempre dará prioridade para os repositories e depois seguirá para o autoload. Não cheguei a procurar nada na documentação sobre a prioridade de execução.

No caso, o seu problema, é que ao adicionar o pacote SimpleCrudPhp, ele depende de variáveis de ambiente que ainda não foram definidas. Acredito que o próprio pacote deveria ter o arquivo .env e não ser algo externo.

No entanto, acredito que talvez alguma dessas soluções devem ajudar:

- Adicionar dentro do repositories, um caminho para o arquivo .env, assim quando o SimpleCrudPhp for executado, ter sido definido as variáveis. (Não sei se funciona)
- Adicionar em seu código, antes de importar todas questões do autoload, o requiremento do arquivo .env, assim antes de executar qualquer coisa, seu programa já carregou as variáveis de ambiente.

Não sei se isso lhe ajuda, mas espero que sim.

Comment: obrigada pela resposta, de fato adicionar o env.php no SimpleCrudPhp resolveria, mas eu (ou outra pessoa) teria que mudar dentro do pacote para cada projeto o local dele. Adicionar o env antes do autoload funciona, mas quando subir para produção (que faz gestão de variáveis de ambiente) sem o env (que deixo no gitignore) faz com que a importação gere erro, já que importa um arquivo que não existe ali.